# Why can I not copy a direcotry from *nix to a mounted smbfs share on Windows 7?

Tags: directory, samba, cp

I've mounted a Windows 7 directory on my FreeBSD box via smbfs:

```
mount
...
//ROOT@BARYONYX/GVKV on /usr/home/gvkv/win (smbfs)
```

but for some reason when I try to copy a directory:

```
cp .vim /win
```

I get the following error:

```
cp: .vim is a directory (not copied).
```

I can copy files just fine. Is there something special about directories and smb shares?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It's nothing to do with smbfs, `cp` always requires the `-r` (recursive) flag to copy a directory. You should get the same if you try to `cp .vim /tmp/`:

```
$ cp .vim /tmp/
cp: omitting directory `.vim'
zsh: exit 1     cp .vim /tmp/
$ cp -r .vim /tmp/
$
```